# Trying to use liquibase on Percona gives error

Tags: mysql, liquibase, percona

I am trying to generateChangeLog for a db on a percona server, i get the below error when i try to do so.

```
Starting Liquibase at Wed, 05 Dec 2018 22:34:37 EST (version 3.6.2 built at 
2018-07-03 11:28:09)
Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: Error during testing for 
MySQL/MariaDB JDBC driver bug: could not retrieve JDBC metadata information 
for temporary table 'TMP_XDBOCVCKWHSQYXKP'
liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: 
liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: 
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: Error during testing for 
MySQL/MariaDB JDBC driver bug: could not retrieve JDBC metadata information 
for temporary table 'TMP_XDBOCVCKWHSQYXKP'
at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1043)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:191)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:129)
    Caused by: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: 
    liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
    liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: Error during testing 
    for MySQL/MariaDB JDBC driver bug: could not retrieve JDBC metadata 
    information for temporary table 'TMP_XDBOCVCKWHSQYXKP'
```

I am trying to use it via command line using below statement

```
liquibase --driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver --classpath=C:/liquibase-3.6.2- 
bin/jars/mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar --changeLogFile=db.changelog- 
1.0.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://REMOTE_SERVER_IP:3306/DB_NAME? 
autoReconnect=true" --username=USER_NAME --password=PASSWORD --logLevel=info 
generateChangeLog
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before? I tried using the old and new JDBC drivers but did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue. Setting the logLevel to debug you could see that Liquibase was creating and dropping a temporary table. That temporary table seemed to cause the issue.

I was able to work-around this issue by using MySQL Workbench to copy the schema to a regular MySQL instance then running generateChangeLog from there.